# loading Texture error in SFML (0x77ADEB85(ntdll.dll))error

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Resource.h"
#include <string>

sf::Texture loadTexture(std::string filename)
{
sf::Texture texture; //0x77ADEB85(ntdll.dll)... error occurs over here 
texture.loadFromFile(filename);
return texture;

}
```

How should I solve this problem? It's an C++ STML Platform jump game.

Comment: Can you provide the specific error that you are getting or output from when you get the error?

Comment: This can be caused by Undefined Behavior in your code. One such undefined behavior is using the wrong binaries for your compiler or perhaps using release binaries for a debug application

Answer (score 0):

You have probably incorrectly linked up SFML with your IDE. Make sure it's connected properly.
You may have forgot to copy dlls to your output folder. Find some resources and it sould be an easy fix.